# How to do Re-indexing programatically in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I need a Re-indexing programatically in magento

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry for that and now you can see question

Comment: Did you search first? There's plenty of these questions already

Answer (score 1):

```
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 

foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
      $process->reindexEverything();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reindex all data:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will reindex each index.
>

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)  
    {  
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();  
    }
```

You can also use the Magento collection model to load each index rather than hard coding the id in the for loop.

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index)  
   {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */  
    $index->reindexAll();  
}
```

You could also call the function getProcessByCode as follows:
>

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think quickway to do it :

reindexAll() method we can reindex all indexes

```
Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->reindexAll();
```